# array_merge_recursive is not working if passing a blank array in between

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, array-merge

I am using array_merge_recursive to merge arrays recursively. Suppose i have following arrays.

```
$arr1,$arr2,$arr3
```

I am using array_merge_recursive to merge these arrays recursively.

```
array_merge_recursive($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
```

If all arrays are having values or not empty then it's working fine. If $arr2 is blank passed then it stops working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Blank in the sense, empty array? or `$arr2` is not an array?

Comment: [Seems to work fine](https://3v4l.org/XD73M) Are you sure that all these are actual arrays, empty or otherwise?

Comment: Blank in the sense is $arr2 is blank.

Comment: @JohnSmith is `$arr2 = '';` or `$arr2 = [];` ?

Comment: @JohnSmith - what do you mean by "blank", blank has no particular meaning in PHP (or even in English), it's too vague a word.... do a var_dump of $arr2 and show us the results

Comment: @MarkBaker i did the same it shows me [] I hope it's cleared.

Comment: And it told you the datatype was an array? Because array_merge_recursive() has no issues with empty arrays, as my link indicates.... a var_dump of an empty array should show `array(0) {
}`, not `[]`.... it should dalways show a datatype, as well as a value

Comment: After var_dump this is the result.
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Can you post an example of a non-working merge on https://3v4l.org/ because we can't replicate your problem.... it may be something in the actual data; but an empty array doesn't cause any problems

Comment: I forgot to mention i am using laravel 5. So it's give me Query Builder instance blank.

Comment: Builder {#451 ▼
  #query: Builder {#447 ▶}
  #model: Transaction {#445 ▼
    #fillable: array:11 [▶]
    #casts: array:1 [▶]
    #location_id: null
    #connection: null
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
  }
  #eagerLoad: []
  #macros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:10 [▶]
}

Comment: So $arr2 is a query builder object? Not an array?

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes you are right. If there is no value in database.

Comment: Then you need to test for that situation, and convert it to an array

Comment: I am doing the same but in case of blank builder object unable to convert? Would you help?

Answer (score 0):

@Kapil Verma:
I had the same problem as you now.
I have a db query which output is placed to an array for each query and some querys don´t generate any data.
I found the solution in Thamilan´s comment.
Just define the array before you try to fill it with data from your query with "$arr2 = [];"
In this case, you have always an existing array, which works for this function.
So the problem from the beginning doesn´t was, that the array is empty, it doesn´t exist really.

Answer (score 0):

You must check your variable by is_array , because we have difference between an blank string and an blank array.

```
$array = array('arr1','arr2','arr3');
$array2 = array();
foreach($array as $a)
{
    if(!is_array($a))  ${$a} = array('');   
}
array_merge_recursive($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
```